# Foreign key filter in a child object

Tags: sql, django, filter, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have the models:

```
class Boss(models.Model):
    fullname = models.TextField()

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    address = models.TextField()
    phone = models.TextField()
    boss = models.ForeignKey(
        Boss, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="shops"
    )

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    phone = models.TextField()
    shop = models.ForeignKey(
        Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employees"
    )
class WorkSpace(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="work_spaces"
    )
```

Serializers:

```
class WorkSpaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkSpace
        fields = ["id","type"]

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    work_spaces = WorkSpaceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ["id","work_spaces","name","phone"]

class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employees = EmployeeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = ["id","employees","phone","name","address"]

class BossSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shops = ShopSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Boss
        fields = ["id","fullname","shops"]
```

View

```
class BossListView(
    ListModelMixin,
    GenericViewSet,
):
    
    queryset = Boss.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BossSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        workspace_type = self.request.query_params.get("workspace_type")
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        if workspace_type:
            qs = qs.filter(shops__employees__work_spaces__type=workspace_type).distinct()
        return qs
```

I filtered with
`Boss.objects.filter(shops__employees__work_spaces__type=C1)`
and got:

```
{
    "shops": [
        {
            "id": 32,
            "name": "Garden flowers",
            "address": "5 st. Hool-Maa",
            "phone": "879124851861598",
            "employees": [
                {
                    "id": 150,
                    "name": "Mike",
                    "phone": "8154451246",
                    "work_spaces": [
                        {
                            "id": 497,
                            "type": "B12"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 15,
                            "type": "Z5"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 33,
                            "type": "C1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But I only need C1 from work_spaces:

```
                [{
                  "id": 33,
                  "type": "C1"
                }]
```

How can I exclude other **work_spaces** from the queryset or do I need to convert the result to a list and then filter using a for loop? There can be many workspaces, and I don't need to show them all to the user, I need information about the Boss, the Shop, the Employee..

Comment: Please add your serializer(s) too

Comment: Could you also share your view ?

Comment: @lbris added view

Comment: Your query seems correct at first sight. Are you sure you have something in `workspace_type` variable in your `get_queryset` method ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your view, you are applying the `lower()` method on the `workspace_type`.

So if you have `workspace_type=C1`, applying `lower()` will make `workspace_type=c1`, and your filter won't match any record.

I make here the assumption that your values have a capital letter.

Comment: Sorry, removed lower()

Comment: Still not working as expected ?

Comment: Yes. My current solution is to use the for loop and remove the other workspace_type from the response in to_representation.